# Netbeans/Git; copy individual files between branches

Tags: git, netbeans, github, branch, github-pages

I'm using Netbeans with Git (hosted on github).

Github uses a special branch in the git repository, "gh-pages", whose content is hosted on their site.

My project generates a stylesheet and demo webpage, which I'm hosting on github to demonstrate the generated stylesheet. In order to do this, I usually just copy the entire "master" branch into "gh-pages" branch and clean-up the "gh-pages" branch afterwards. Needless to say this isn't the most ideal way of working.

I'd like to be able to copy a single file from the "master" branch into the "gh-pages" branch, preferably using just Netbeans' builtin Git support. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure about netbeans. But you can simply checkout the file from master when on the other branch with:

```
git checkout master -- path/to/the/file/you/want/file.txt
```

Also, you can read out the file with

```
git show master:path/to/the/file/you/want/file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

**Netbeans 8**
Go to the Projects tab where the project files tree is,

1. Right-click on the file and Git-> Checkout -> Files.
2. tick 'Update Index with ..."
3. "*select*" revision
4. *checkout*